# Number of non-negative integer solutions for linear equations with constants

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, diophantine-equations, generating-functions

How do we find the number of non-negative integer solutions for linear equation of the form:

$$a \cdot x + b \cdot y = c$$

Where $a, b, c$ are constants and $x,y$ are the variables ?

Comment: Generating functions might help - the count is the coefficient of $x^c$ in $\dfrac{1}{(1-x^a)(1-x^b)}$.

Comment: Is there a known case where the number of solutions is not either $0$ or $\infty$? If $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$, then any time $b | ka(1-c)$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then both $x$ and $y$ are integer solutions and I think there are infinitely many values of $k$ that solve the above. If any of the coefficients are irrational, then there are no integer solutions.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 - Yes, the number of sols is not either 0 or Infinity

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85, note that $x, y \ge 0$, so there are not infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Have you found any answers for specific situations? For instance, if we assume that $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$ and that $y = k \cdot \operatorname{lcm}(b_n,b_d)$, where $b = b_n/b_d$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, can you find ranges of $a$ and $c$ such that there are infinitely many or zero solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but a relatively simple one and approximate one. By Schur's theorem of combinatorics<sup>?</sup>, the number of solutions is asymptotically ($c \to \infty$):

$$ \frac{c}{ab} $$

---

Schur's theorem of combinatorics states that the number of solutions of (with $a_i$ relatively prime):

$$ \sum_{i=1}^M a_i x_i = c $$

is:

$$ \frac{c^{M-1}}{(M-1)!\prod a_i} $$

---

<sup>?</sup> This name is used by Wilf's Generatingfunctionology, but I cannot seem to find it elsewhere. It appears that Schur has many theorems.

Comment: I love Generatingfunctionology!

Comment: @George V. Williams - Thanks, probably this might be the easiest way to get the desired result. 
Could you pls explain what is 'n' in the above equation ?

Comment: @darthy734, my apologies, I wrote $n$ instead of $c$. It's fixed now.

Comment: You don't really need all of Schur for this - it is sort of obvious that $c/ab$ is approximation.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Also, for c=5, M=2, a1=1, a2=2 this gives 2.5...

Comment: @EllaShar, it's asymptotic to the exact number of solutions as $c \to \infty$, not exact.

Comment: Oh. It never says so about the third expression

Answer (score -1):

You might be looking for Diophantine equations.

Check [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Solve-a-Linear-Diophantine-Equation) or [this](http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/2006/06CohenLectures.pdf) for an explanation!

Comment: He's not looking for how to solve it, he's looking for how to count non-negative solutions.

Comment: Maybe he was looking for small solution sets. Added because it provides a way to count solutions, mon ami.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - Can you please throw some more light on the generating functions method.

Comment: @AnuragPallaprolu - Going through the link you've shared, will let you know once I'm done.

Comment: @AnuragPallaprolu - Thanks for the link, but as Thomas mentioned, is there a way to get the number of non-neg solutions rather than solve for the whole set ?

Comment: @darthy734 You could use Generating functions, yes. Please check [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/.../lecture06.ppt‎)link for an entertaining discussion on Generating functions. This might solve your problem

Comment: @AnuragPallaprolu - Could you please update the link, it seems to be broken.

Comment: @darthy734 Please follow the URL. I think MSE doesn't allow documents to be linked via hyperlink. Copy and paste the link to your browser. Or [this](http://goo.gl/rP2RP). The first link is what I was looking at.

Comment: @AnuragPallaprolu - Thanks !